# Refactoring HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, refactoring

I know you do commonly refactor code for the back-end to improve it's speed, security or make it more readable for the next person who takes over your project, but do you refactor html and css? Since they are markup languages it doesn't seem so trivial, besides wiping off a few bytes of your code vs the time input looking for alternatives doesn't seem to be worth the effort, especially if you are working on a tight deadline.

Comment: you may want to look over this
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are innumerable things that can increase or decrease page performance. Like with any optimisation though, you should start with where people are seeing problems or slowdown.

On a broader level, reducing payloads to the smallest possible size makes a big difference. This involves gzip, caching, and minification. You can rewrite your code a thousand times but it probably won't end up much smaller if at all than it would if you were to use gzip and minify your CSS — but don't minify HTML as it's too prone to rendering issues.

On a finer level, specific CSS features such as resizing large images and implementing lots of browser-generated gradients and shadows can bring performance down significantly. If you're noticing sluggishness when scrolling then things like this are probably what you need to focus on. Just one image that's 640x480 or more being resized by CSS can bring performance crashing down in some browsers.

Then of course there's latency. Using content distribution networks or at the very least highly optimised servers will ensure your HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and image files are delivered to users and shown as quickly as possible.